# Converting JavaScript back to readable HTML in Python script

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping

I am using Python to scrape a website. The return is JS code in between  tags. What is the best approach to convert this back to readable HTML or anything humanely readable again? This is what was returned after I scraped the web page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.NREUM||(NREUM={});NREUM.info={"beacon":"bam.nr-data.net","errorBeacon":"bam.nr-data.net","licenseKey":"3eaa5bdc0e","applicationID":"90760185","transactionName":"cAoMEUBcDQ4BFxoXVFIGFkpQUhIH","queueTime":0,"applicationTime":6,"agent":""}</script>
<script type="text/javascript">(window.NREUM||(NREUM={})).loader_config={xpid:"VQQPWFNQCRAJVFZUBwAPUw=="};window.NREUM||(NREUM={}),__nr_require=function(t,n,e){function r(e){if(!n[e]){var o=n[e]={exports:{}};t[e][0].call(o.exports,function(n){var o=t[e][1][n];return r(o||n)},o,o.exports)}return n[e].exports}if("function"==typeof __nr_require)return __nr_require;for(var o=0;o<e.length;o++)r(e[o]);return r}({1:[function(t,n,e){function r(t){try{s.console&&console.log(t)}catch(n){}}var o,i=t("ee"),a=t(16),s={};try{o=localStorage.getItem("__nr_flags").split(","),console&&"function"==typeof console.log&&(s.console=!0,o.indexOf("dev")!==-1&&(s.dev=!0),o.indexOf("nr_dev")!==-1&&(s.nrDev=!0))}catch(c){}s.nrDev&&i.on("internal-error",function(t){r(t.stack)}),s.dev&&i.on("fn-err",function(t,n,e){r(e.stack)}),s.dev&&(r("NR AGENT IN DEVELOPMENT MODE"),r("flags: "+a(s,function(t,n){return t}).join(", ")))},{}],2:[function(t,n,e){function r(t,n,e,r,s){try{p?p-=1:o(s||new UncaughtException(t,n,e),!0)}catch(f){try{i("ierr",[f,c.now(),!0])}catch(d){}}return"function"==typeof u&&u.apply(this,a(arguments))}function UncaughtException(t,n,e){this.message=t||"Uncaught error with no additional information",this.sourceURL=n,this.line=e}function o(t,n){var e=n?null:c.now();i("err",[t,e])}var i=t("handle"),a=t(17),s=t("ee"),c=t("loader"),f=t("gos"),u=window.onerror,d=!1,l="nr@seenError",p=0;c.features.err=!0,t(1),window.onerror=r;try{throw new Error}catch(h){"stack"in h&&(t(8),t(7),"addEventListener"in window&&t(5),c.xhrWrappable&&t(9),d=!0)}s.on("fn-start",function(t,n,e){d&&(p+=1)}),s.on("fn-err",function(t,n,e){d&&!e[l]&&(f(e,l,function(){return!0}),this.thrown=!0,o(e))}),s.on("fn-end",function(){d&&!this.thrown&&p>0&&(p-=1)}),s.on("internal-error",function(t){i("ierr",[t,c.now(),!0])})},{}],3:[function(t,n,e){t("loader").features.ins=!0},{}],4:[function(t,n,e){function r(t){}if(window.performance&&window.performance.timing&&window.performance.getEntriesByType){var o=t("ee"),i=t("handle"),a=t(8),s=t(7),c="learResourceTimings",f="addEventListener",u="resourcetimingbufferfull",d="bstResource",l="resource",p="-start",h="-end",m="fn"+p,v="fn"+h,w="bstTimer",y="pushState",g=t("loader");g.features.stn=!0,t(6);var b=NREUM.o.EV;o.on(m,function(t,n){var e=t[0];e instanceof b&&(this.bstStart=g.now())}),o.on(v,function(t,n){var e=t[0];e instanceof b&&i("bst",[e,n,this.bstStart,g.now()])}),a.on(m,function(t,n,e){this.bstStart=g.now(),this.bstType=e}),a.on(v,function(t,n){i(w,[n,this.bstStart,g.now(),this.bstType])}),s.on(m,function(){this.bstStart=g.now()}),s.on(v,function(t,n){i(w,[n,this.bstStart,g.now(),"requestAnimationFrame"])}),o.on(y+p,function(t){this.time=g.now(),this.startPath=location.pathname+location.hash}),o.on(y+h,function(t){i("bstHist",[location.pathname+location.hash,this.startPath,this.time])}),f in window.performance&&(window.performance["c"+c]?window.performance[f](u,function(t){i(d,[window.performance.getEntriesByType(l)]),window.performance["c"+c]()},!1):window.performance[f]("webkit"+u,function(t){i(d,[window.performance.getEntriesByType(l)]),window.performance["webkitC"+c]()},!1)),document[f]("scroll",r,{passive:!0}),document[f]("keypress",r,!1),document[f]("click",r,!1)}},{}],5:[function(t,n,e){function r(t){for(var n=t;n&&!n.hasOwnProperty(u);)n=Object.getPrototypeOf(n);n&&o(n)}function o(t){s.inPlace(t,[u,d],"-",i)}function i(t,n){return t[1]}var a=t("ee").get("events"),s=t(19)(a,!0),c=t("gos"),f=XMLHttpRequest,u="addEventListener",d="removeEventListener";n.exports=a,"getPrototypeOf"in Object?(r(document),r(window),r(f.prototype)):f.prototype.hasOwnProperty(u)&&(o(window),o(f.prototype)),a.on(u+"-start",function(t,n){var e=t[1],r=c(e,"nr@wrapped",function(){function t(){if("function"==typeof e.handleEvent)return e.handleEvent.apply(e,arguments)}var n={object:t,"function":e}[typeof e];return n?s(n,"fn-",null,n.name||"anonymous"):e});this.wrapped=t[1]=r}),a.on(d+"-start",function(t){t[1]=this.wrapped||t[1]})},{}],6:[function(t,n,e){var r=t("ee").get("history"),o=t(19)(r);n.exports=r,o.inPlace(window.history,["pushState","replaceState"],"-")},{}],7:[function(t,n,e){var r=t("ee").get("raf"),o=t(19)(r),i="equestAnimationFrame";n.exports=r,o.inPlace(window,["r"+i,"mozR"+i,"webkitR"+i,"msR"+i],"raf-"),r.on("raf-start",function(t){t[0]=o(t[0],"fn-")})},{}],8:[function(t,n,e){function r(t,n,e){t[0]=a(t[0],"fn-",null,e)}function o(t,n,e){this.method=e,this.timerDuration=isNaN(t[1])?0:+t[1],t[0]=a(t[0],"fn-",this,e)}var i=t("ee").get("timer"),a=t(19)(i),s="setTimeout",c="setInterval",f="clearTimeout",u="-start",d="-";n.exports=i,a.inPlace(window,[s,"setImmediate"],s+d),a.inPlace(window,[c],c+d),a.inPlace(window,[f,"clearImmediate"],f+d),i.on(c+u,r),i.on(s+u,o)},{}],9:[function(t,n,e){function r(t,n){d.inPlace(n,["onreadystatechange"],"fn-",s)}function o(){var t=this,n=u.context(t);t.readyState>3&&!n.resolved&&(n.resolved=!0,u.emit("xhr-resolved",[],t)),d.inPlace(t,y,"fn-",s)}function i(t){g.push(t),h&&(x?x.then(a):v?v(a):(E=-E,O.data=E))}function a(){for(var t=0;t<g.length;t++)r([],g[t]);g.length&&(g=[])}function s(t,n){return n}function c(t,n){for(var e in t)n[e]=t[e];return n}t(5);var f=t("ee"),u=f.get("xhr"),d=t(19)(u),l=NREUM.o,p=l.XHR,h=l.MO,m=l.PR,v=l.SI,w="readystatechange",y=["onload","onerror","onabort","onloadstart","onloadend","onprogress","ontimeout"],g=[];n.exports=u;var b=window.XMLHttpRequest=function(t){var n=new p(t);try{u.emit("new-xhr",[n],n),n.addEventListener(w,o,!1)}catch(e){try{u.emit("internal-error",[e])}catch(r){}}return n};if(c(p,b),b.prototype=p.prototype,d.inPlace(b.prototype,["open","send"],"-xhr-",s),u.on("send-xhr-start",function(t,n){r(t,n),i(n)}),u.on("open-xhr-start",r),h){var x=m&&m.resolve();if(!v&&!m){var E=1,O=document.createTextNode(E);new h(a).observe(O,{characterData:!0})}}else f.on("fn-end",function(t){t[0]&&t[0].type===w||a()})},{}],10:[function(t,n,e){function r(t){var n=this.params,e=this.metrics;if(!this.ended){this.ended=!0;for(var r=0;r<d;r++)t.removeEventListener(u[r],this.listener,!1);if(!n.aborted){if(e.duration=a.now()-this.startTime,4===t.readyState){n.status=t.status;var i=o(t,this.lastSize);if(i&&(e.rxSize=i),this.sameOrigin){var c=t.getResponseHeader("X-NewRelic-App-Data");c&&(n.cat=c.split(", ").pop())}}else n.status=0;e.cbTime=this.cbTime,f.emit("xhr-done",[t],t),s("xhr",[n,e,this.startTime])}}}function o(t,n){var e=t.responseType;if("json"===e&&null!==n)return n;var r="arraybuffer"===e||"blob"===e||"json"===e?t.response:t.responseText;return h(r)}function i(t,n){var e=c(n),r=t.params;r.host=e.hostname+":"+e.port,r.pathname=e.pathname,t.sameOrigin=e.sameOrigin}var a=t("loader");if(a.xhrWrappable){var s=t("handle"),c=t(11),f=t("ee"),u=["load","error","abort","timeout"],d=u.length,l=t("id"),p=t(14),h=t(13),m=window.XMLHttpRequest;a.features.xhr=!0,t(9),f.on("new-xhr",function(t){var n=this;n.totalCbs=0,n.called=0,n.cbTime=0,n.end=r,n.ended=!1,n.xhrGuids={},n.lastSize=null,p&&(p>34||p<10)||window.opera||t.addEventListener("progress",function(t){n.lastSize=t.loaded},!1)}),f.on("open-xhr-start",function(t){this.params={method:t[0]},i(this,t[1]),this.metrics={}}),f.on("open-xhr-end",function(t,n){"loader_config"in NREUM&&"xpid"in NREUM.loader_config&&this.sameOrigin&&n.setRequestHeader("X-NewRelic-ID",NREUM.loader_config.xpid)}),f.on("send-xhr-start",function(t,n){var e=this.metrics,r=t[0],o=this;if(e&&r){var i=h(r);i&&(e.txSize=i)}this.startTime=a.now(),this.listener=function(t){try{"abort"===t.type&&(o.params.aborted=!0),("load"!==t.type||o.called===o.totalCbs&&(o.onloadCalled||"function"!=typeof n.onload))&&o.end(n)}catch(e){try{f.emit("internal-error",[e])}catch(r){}}};for(var s=0;s<d;s++)n.addEventListener(u[s],this.listener,!1)}),f.on("xhr-cb-time",function(t,n,e){this.cbTime+=t,n?this.onloadCalled=!0:this.called+=1,this.called!==this.totalCbs||!this.onloadCalled&&"function"==typeof e.onload||this.end(e)}),f.on("xhr-load-added",function(t,n){var e=""+l(t)+!!n;this.xhrGuids&&!this.xhrGuids[e]&&(this.xhrGuids[e]=!0,this.totalCbs+=1)}),f.on("xhr-load-removed",function(t,n){var e=""+l(t)+!!n;this.xhrGuids&&this.xhrGuids[e]&&(delete this.xhrGuids[e],this.totalCbs-=1)}),f.on("addEventListener-end",function(t,n){n instanceof m&&"load"===t[0]&&f.emit("xhr-load-added",[t[1],t[2]],n)}),f.on("removeEventListener-end",function(t,n){n instanceof m&&"load"===t[0]&&f.emit("xhr-load-removed",[t[1],t[2]],n)}),f.on("fn-start",function(t,n,e){n instanceof m&&("onload"===e&&(this.onload=!0),("load"===(t[0]&&t[0].type)||this.onload)&&(this.xhrCbStart=a.now()))}),f.on("fn-end",function(t,n){this.xhrCbStart&&f.emit("xhr-cb-time",[a.now()-this.xhrCbStart,this.onload,n],n)})}},{}],11:[function(t,n,e){n.exports=function(t){var n=document.createElement("a"),e=window.location,r={};n.href=t,r.port=n.port;var o=n.href.split("://");!r.port&&o[1]&&(r.port=o[1].split("/")[0].split("@").pop().split(":")[1]),r.port&&"0"!==r.port||(r.port="https"===o[0]?"443":"80"),r.hostname=n.hostname||e.hostname,r.pathname=n.pathname,r.protocol=o[0],"/"!==r.pathname.charAt(0)&&(r.pathname="/"+r.pathname);var i=!n.protocol||":"===n.protocol||n.protocol===e.protocol,a=n.hostname===document.domain&&n.port===e.port;return r.sameOrigin=i&&(!n.hostname||a),r}},{}],12:[function(t,n,e){function r(){}function o(t,n,e){return function(){return i(t,[f.now()].concat(s(arguments)),n?null:this,e),n?void 0:this}}var i=t("handle"),a=t(16),s=t(17),c=t("ee").get("tracer"),f=t("loader"),u=NREUM;"undefined"==typeof window.newrelic&&(newrelic=u);var d=["setPageViewName","setCustomAttribute","setErrorHandler","finished","addToTrace","inlineHit","addRelease"],l="api-",p=l+"ixn-";a(d,function(t,n){u[n]=o(l+n,!0,"api")}),u.addPageAction=o(l+"addPageAction",!0),u.setCurrentRouteName=o(l+"routeName",!0),n.exports=newrelic,u.interaction=function(){return(new r).get()};var h=r.prototype={createTracer:function(t,n){var e={},r=this,o="function"==typeof n;return i(p+"tracer",[f.now(),t,e],r),function(){if(c.emit((o?"":"no-")+"fn-start",[f.now(),r,o],e),o)try{return n.apply(this,arguments)}catch(t){throw c.emit("fn-err",[arguments,this,t],e),t}finally{c.emit("fn-end",[f.now()],e)}}}};a("actionText,setName,setAttribute,save,ignore,onEnd,getContext,end,get".split(","),function(t,n){h[n]=o(p+n)}),newrelic.noticeError=function(t){"string"==typeof t&&(t=new Error(t)),i("err",[t,f.now()])}},{}],13:[function(t,n,e){n.exports=function(t){if("string"==typeof t&&t.length)return t.length;if("object"==typeof t){if("undefined"!=typeof ArrayBuffer&&t instanceof ArrayBuffer&&t.byteLength)return t.byteLength;if("undefined"!=typeof Blob&&t instanceof Blob&&t.size)return t.size;if(!("undefined"!=typeof FormData&&t instanceof FormData))try{return JSON.stringify(t).length}catch(n){return}}}},{}],14:[function(t,n,e){var r=0,o=navigator.userAgent.match(/Firefox[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/);o&&(r=+o[1]),n.exports=r},{}],15:[function(t,n,e){function r(t,n){if(!o)return!1;if(t!==o)return!1;if(!n)return!0;if(!i)return!1;for(var e=i.split("."),r=n.split("."),a=0;a<r.length;a++)if(r[a]!==e[a])return!1;return!0}var o=null,i=null,a=/Version\/(\S+)\s+Safari/;if(navigator.userAgent){var s=navigator.userAgent,c=s.match(a);c&&s.indexOf("Chrome")===-1&&s.indexOf("Chromium")===-1&&(o="Safari",i=c[1])}n.exports={agent:o,version:i,match:r}},{}],16:[function(t,n,e){function r(t,n){var e=[],r="",i=0;for(r in t)o.call(t,r)&&(e[i]=n(r,t[r]),i+=1);return e}var o=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;n.exports=r},{}],17:[function(t,n,e){function r(t,n,e){n||(n=0),"undefined"==typeof e&&(e=t?t.length:0);for(var r=-1,o=e-n||0,i=Array(o<0?0:o);++r<o;)i[r]=t[n+r];return i}n.exports=r},{}],18:[function(t,n,e){n.exports={exists:"undefined"!=typeof window.performance&&window.performance.timing&&"undefined"!=typeof window.performance.timing.navigationStart}},{}],19:[function(t,n,e){function r(t){return!(t&&t instanceof Function&&t.apply&&!t[a])}var o=t("ee"),i=t(17),a="nr@original",s=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,c=!1;n.exports=function(t,n){function e(t,n,e,o){function nrWrapper(){var r,a,s,c;try{a=this,r=i(arguments),s="function"==typeof e?e(r,a):e||{}}catch(f){l([f,"",[r,a,o],s])}u(n+"start",[r,a,o],s);try{return c=t.apply(a,r)}catch(d){throw u(n+"err",[r,a,d],s),d}finally{u(n+"end",[r,a,c],s)}}return r(t)?t:(n||(n=""),nrWrapper[a]=t,d(t,nrWrapper),nrWrapper)}function f(t,n,o,i){o||(o="");var a,s,c,f="-"===o.charAt(0);for(c=0;c<n.length;c++)s=n[c],a=t[s],r(a)||(t[s]=e(a,f?s+o:o,i,s))}function u(e,r,o){if(!c||n){var i=c;c=!0;try{t.emit(e,r,o,n)}catch(a){l([a,e,r,o])}c=i}}function d(t,n){if(Object.defineProperty&&Object.keys)try{var e=Object.keys(t);return e.forEach(function(e){Object.defineProperty(n,e,{get:function(){return t[e]},set:function(n){return t[e]=n,n}})}),n}catch(r){l([r])}for(var o in t)s.call(t,o)&&(n[o]=t[o]);return n}function l(n){try{t.emit("internal-error",n)}catch(e){}}return t||(t=o),e.inPlace=f,e.flag=a,e}},{}],ee:[function(t,n,e){function r(){}function o(t){function n(t){return t&&t instanceof r?t:t?c(t,s,i):i()}function e(e,r,o,i){if(!l.aborted||i){t&&t(e,r,o);for(var a=n(o),s=m(e),c=s.length,f=0;f<c;f++)s[f].apply(a,r);var d=u[g[e]];return d&&d.push([b,e,r,a]),a}}function p(t,n){y[t]=m(t).concat(n)}function h(t,n){var e=y[t];if(e)for(var r=0;r<e.length;r++)e[r]===n&&e.splice(r,1)}function m(t){return y[t]||[]}function v(t){return d[t]=d[t]||o(e)}function w(t,n){f(t,function(t,e){n=n||"feature",g[e]=n,n in u||(u[n]=[])})}var y={},g={},b={on:p,addEventListener:p,removeEventListener:h,emit:e,get:v,listeners:m,context:n,buffer:w,abort:a,aborted:!1};return b}function i(){return new r}function a(){(u.api||u.feature)&&(l.aborted=!0,u=l.backlog={})}var s="nr@context",c=t("gos"),f=t(16),u={},d={},l=n.exports=o();l.backlog=u},{}],gos:[function(t,n,e){function r(t,n,e){if(o.call(t,n))return t[n];var r=e();if(Object.defineProperty&&Object.keys)try{return Object.defineProperty(t,n,{value:r,writable:!0,enumerable:!1}),r}catch(i){}return t[n]=r,r}var o=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;n.exports=r},{}],handle:[function(t,n,e){function r(t,n,e,r){o.buffer([t],r),o.emit(t,n,e)}var o=t("ee").get("handle");n.exports=r,r.ee=o},{}],id:[function(t,n,e){function r(t){var n=typeof t;return!t||"object"!==n&&"function"!==n?-1:t===window?0:a(t,i,function(){return o++})}var o=1,i="nr@id",a=t("gos");n.exports=r},{}],loader:[function(t,n,e){function r(){if(!E++){var t=x.info=NREUM.info,n=p.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];if(setTimeout(u.abort,3e4),!(t&&t.licenseKey&&t.applicationID&&n))return u.abort();f(g,function(n,e){t[n]||(t[n]=e)}),c("mark",["onload",a()+x.offset],null,"api");var e=p.createElement("script");e.src="https://"+t.agent,n.parentNode.insertBefore(e,n)}}function o(){"complete"===p.readyState&&i()}function i(){c("mark",["domContent",a()+x.offset],null,"api")}function a(){return O.exists&&performance.now?Math.round(performance.now()):(s=Math.max((new Date).getTime(),s))-x.offset}var s=(new Date).getTime(),c=t("handle"),f=t(16),u=t("ee"),d=t(15),l=window,p=l.document,h="addEventListener",m="attachEvent",v=l.XMLHttpRequest,w=v&&v.prototype;NREUM.o={ST:setTimeout,SI:l.setImmediate,CT:clearTimeout,XHR:v,REQ:l.Request,EV:l.Event,PR:l.Promise,MO:l.MutationObserver};var y=""+location,g={beacon:"bam.nr-data.net",errorBeacon:"bam.nr-data.net",agent:"js-agent.newrelic.com/nr-1099.min.js"},b=v&&w&&w[h]&&!/CriOS/.test(navigator.userAgent),x=n.exports={offset:s,now:a,origin:y,features:{},xhrWrappable:b,userAgent:d};t(12),p[h]?(p[h]("DOMContentLoaded",i,!1),l[h]("load",r,!1)):(p[m]("onreadystatechange",o),l[m]("onload",r)),c("mark",["firstbyte",s],null,"api");var E=0,O=t(18)},{}]},{},["loader",2,10,4,3]);</script>
```

Edit 1:

The website I'm trying to extract is https://upbit.com/service_center/notice
Its their news page. It is protected by cloudflare so I'm using the a library to handle that bypass.

Code below:

```
import cfscrape

scraper = cfscrape.create_scraper(delay=15)  # returns a CloudflareScraper instance
# Or: scraper = cfscrape.CloudflareScraper()  # CloudflareScraper inherits from requests.Session
print scraper.get("https://upbit.com/service_center/notice").content  # => "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>..."
```

I see the script tags on the web page when I inspect it along with a lot more content but only the script tags and some external static html show up when I print out the contents from the scrape.

Comment: What do you mean by "Readable HTML"?... It's just javascript, and likely minified. You may think about using a beautifier: https://beautifier.io/ and find a REST api for it. This may also be obfuscated.

Comment: The webpage also contains HTML. I'm fairly confident they are dynmically creating the other HTML on the webpage using JavaScript script blocks. I just need to find a way to make this readable. It doesn't necessarily need to be HTML but I imagine some type of 'conversion' is taking place later on to convert it back to HTML so it is displayed on the web page.

Comment: In that case, you need to **wait** for the page to be fully ready (hence in some way register to the DOMLoaded event), then get the rendered source. Not sure how to do that with python, but that's what you should in someway do.

Comment: Can you provide the URL? And what have you tried?

Comment: Sure see my edit I made