# How to extract data from upbit.com website

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping

I am readdressing a question that I created a few months ago and I lost access to my account but happened to stumble upon this question while I was searching around. 
My original post was here [Converting JavaScript back to readable HTML in Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53795060/converting-javascript-back-to-readable-html-in-python-script) .The problem that I am experiencing is I am not getting the full HTML markup back from the website when you try to webscrape it. Upbit.com is protected by cloudflare so I am using a module in python to bypass is called cfscrape. The cloudflare module works and gets me a partial html markup when I output it in a variable but it is not getting the nested HTML tags at all. The tag that I am trying to extract from starts at a div tag with an id called "root". In the console it only show that div tag with <...> in between the open and close tag of that div. I am still using the same code as before so nothing has changed. My best guess now is to try to extract the cookie and maybe pass it into a python curl request? But I am completely unsure of how to do that and hence why I am reaching out to Stack. I am also totally willing to use other programming languages.

```
import cfscrape

scraper = cfscrape.create_scraper(delay=15)  # returns a CloudflareScraper instance
# Or: scraper = cfscrape.CloudflareScraper()  # CloudflareScraper inherits from requests.Session
print scraper.get("https://upbit.com/service_center/notice").content  # => "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>..."
```

Edit 1: This is the data that I'm trying to extract. The information I'm looking for is in a table. I want to retrieve each  tag within this table since this contains the content showed on the webpage.
[image]

Edit 2: Okay I figured out what data needed to be passed off to bypass cloudflare authentication every time using the standard "request" library in Python. The issue that I am having now is even this is not getting nested tags still. When I make a request it just gets the top level "root" tag but not the tags inside of that div tag (as shown in my picture). I have never seen anything like this typically when you do a get request it returns all the html content on the webpage. Does anyone have any ideas why this would be happening??? I'm convinced they are somehow hiding the information using JavaScript, but I don't understand JavaScript enough to know what to look for when someone would try to obfuscate it.

```
import cfscrape
import requests
import time
request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"

scraper = cfscrape.create_scraper(delay=15)

cookie_value, user_agent = cfscrape.get_cookie_string("https://upbit.com/service_center/notice", user_agent='Mozilla/5.0')
request += "Cookie: %s\r\nUser-Agent: %s\r\n" % (cookie_value, user_agent)

#print request

temp = cookie_value.split('; __cfduid=')
cf_clearance = temp[0].split('cf_clearance=')
#print temp[1]
#print cf_clearance[1]
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
cookies = {'cf_clearance': cf_clearance[1], '__cfduid':temp[1]}

r = requests.get("https://upbit.com/service_center/notice", cookies=cookies, headers=headers).content
print r
```

Comment: could you show more of the html you are trying to get back please? Use the snippet tool via [edit] to insert.

Comment: sure can do @QHarr

Comment: have you tried https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape or https://html-agility-pack.net/knowledge-base/32425973/how-can-i-get-html-from-page-with-cloudflare-ddos-portection- ?

Comment: @begin29 my current solution is using the cloudflare-scrape library to mitigate the cloudflare protection page. That 2nd link that you provide looks like it may be doing exactly what that cloudflare-scrape does except its written in C#. Is there an advantage instead of doing this in C# rather than in Python?

Comment: I don't think so about any C# advantage solution. The main thing with cloudflare protection, they always update protection methods and you should find library with recent updates or write it for self.

Comment: @begin29 The cloudflare bypass really isn't the problem anymore (my new edit shows the code on how I bypass that). But the content scraping is still not getting all the markup on the page...